# How to get the SharePoint URL in C# with "https"?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, asp.net

How to get the SharePoint site secured URL(https) ,present I am using this :

```
SPWeb web= web app.Sites[0].RootWeb;

string example = web.URl+"/sites/pages/...../....aspx";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SPWebApplication webapp = this.Parent as SPWebApplication;                   
string example = webapp.Sites[0].RootWeb; //from this you will get the http link                                    
   string securedModeURL =web.Url.Replace("http","https") ;
```

//here you will change https , you will get the secured link of the site i.e., "https://example.com"

Answer (score 1):

You can get your Web URL by using the piece of code below :

```
string example = SPContext.Current.Web.Url+"/pages/...../....aspx";
```

or

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
{
      using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
      {
         string example = web.Url+"/pages/...../....aspx";
      }
}
```

**NOTE :** **SPContext.Current.Web.Url** gives the Url of the site whether root or inner site

Comment: thank you but i am getting null exception in timerjob

Comment: I am trying to get the https link of the particular page and include that in email and send to the users using the timer job every week, like weekly updates

Comment: Yes you will get null you do not have access to Context because the timer job does not run within a context.

Comment: Try this code to get url in the **Execute()** methode :

SPWebApplication webapp = this.Parent as SPWebApplication;
string example = webapp.Sites[0].RootWeb.Url;

Comment: SPWebApplication webapp = this.Parent as SPWebApplication;                                           string example = webapp.Sites[0].RootWeb;                                                 string securedModeURL =web.Url.Replace("http","https") ;     wrote this and solved my problem able to get the secured link (https) ,thankyou for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `HttpContext` and then use `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url` to get the URL of current page.

Using `SPContext.Current.Web` you can get the SPWeb surrounding the page you're on, and thus its URL will be the URL of the Web, not the current page you are on.